# Change GridView GroupStyle in VisualState

Tags: xaml, gridview, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

In my Windows 8.1 WinRT/XAML app I have a grouped `GridView` with a corresponding `GroupStyle`:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource groupedViewSource}}">
    ...
    <GridView.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    ...
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <VariableSizedWrapGrid 
                         Style="{StaticResource NormalWrapGridStyle}" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
        </GroupStyle>
    </GridView.GroupStyle>
</GridView>
```

Now this is the version for a fullscreen view. What I want is to adapt the UI of the GridView for smaller display widths, e.g. in Portrait mode. Thus I want to adapt the `GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate` for smaller headers and the `GroupStyle.Panel` for less margin around single GridView groups.

Normally I'm doing such UI adaptions using a different VisualState, but it seems not to be possible to set a different `GroupStyle` in a VisualState or to change the according templates. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What's stopping you from using a different Gridview for Portrait orientation? You can detect the current orientation to hide/show appropriate content, see my blog post for more info on how to do this http://www.zubairahmed.net/?p=1032

Comment: Of course, this is a trivial solution. But: I don't want to duplicate my GridView just for the purpose of adapting some styling. Doing that and not being able to do it with VisualStates is very ugly.

Comment: I know that many years have passed but very clearly, even if this might have been a forced approach back then, it isn't any more. Two different controls don't provide a view of the same data. The official approach supported by MS is to use visual states to change whatever you need to change, style or templates or both, based on responsive and adaptive triggers or your own code to change that states.

Answer (score 0):

I am with @Zubair on this one. If you can make multiple layouts for each orientation you have a better solution overall. You can abstract them into user controls if you like. You can reuse the data templates if you like. But handling both orientation AND monitor scaling in a single layout is a needless over-complexity.

> Read this: http://blog.jerrynixon.com/2013/12/the-two-ways-to-handle-orientation-in.html

If you *must* do it like you are wanting, which I do not recommend, you might look at this solution: http://xaml.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#MVA/201311_Blend/XamlSpace/ViewModels/MainPageViewModel.cs You can download the whole project if you like. Again, it's not what I would do.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it doesn't look like you can do this, even now, after so many years, on W10 UWP. You have to resort to code:

```
GridView.GroupStyle.Clear();
```

to clear, or to

```
GridView.GroupStyle.Clear();
GridView.GroupStyle.Add((GroupStyle)Resources["YourGroupStyleKey"]);
```

to set, from the code where your use your `VisualStateManager.GoToState()`, anyway.